# chrome.storage.session in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I have chrome extension which keeps information in session storage by `chrome.storage.session.set` and I have to convert that extension to firefox. In firefox `browser.storage.session` doesnt work so what is my alternative solution in this case.

`chrome.storage.session.set({ key: value });`

First I tried by creating variable in `background.js` by it's looks like extension clears all variables after few minutes.

```
let key;

case "save-key":
    key= request.value;
  break;
```

How to achieve session storage in firefox extension?

Comment: In Firefox the background script has access to the classic [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) which stores only strings so you'll need to use JSON.stringify and JSON.parse.